# Redirecting Admin account on Admin panel in vb.net 2010?

Tags: database, vb.net, user-accounts

Can you guys help me. I want to redirect admin account to admin panel, 
the scenario is : 
i will log in as admin account it will be redirect to admin panel then if it's not it will redirect to users form .

This is my code:

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Loginform

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter
        AcceptButton = loginbutton
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles loginbutton.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Users.mdb;")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [Usertable] WHERE [usernameField] = username and [passwordField] = password", con)

        Dim usernameparam As New OleDbParameter("username", usertxt.Text)
        Dim passwordparam As New OleDbParameter("password", passtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(usernameparam)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(passwordparam)
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Login Successful", vbInformation, "Logged In.")
            usertxt.Clear()
            passtxt.Clear()
        ElseIf usertxt.Text = Nothing And passtxt.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please input your correct Information.", vbExclamation, "Error!")

        Else
            MsgBox("Login Fail!" + vbCrLf + "Possible Problems:" + vbCrLf + "*Wrong Information(Password,Username)" + vbCrLf + "*Record is absent in database", vbCritical, "Try Again.")
            usertxt.Clear()
            passtxt.Clear()
        End If
        cmd.Connection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any forms here...

Comment: Also what determines the admin role, I can see you just doing a lookup, is there other types of users?

Comment: yep i did not include the forms, i want to focus on the part where admin's account will be redirect to its panel.

Comment: What determines an admin role, what other types of roles if any? I've already asked this, but you didn't give me an answer...

Comment: I would hope some kind of column you have setup to know what role that user is in.